# Published expo app, running in expo on iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I just built my first react-native app through expo and published it for the client to view. They can click the link on their android (where they downloaded expo client) and it opens and runs fine. WHen they click it on their iPhone (also downloaded expo iOS app) it opens expo and then returns a message that it can' load and to go back to the expo home page basically.

I've built this app specifically with iOS and android in mind and I thought that expo handles that for both published testing and deployment to the app stores, however, I don't want to have to pay the iOS 99 dollar fee yet just to let them test this on an iPhone.

Does anyone know why a successfully published app that opens on android through expo won't open on iOS devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly you have to use Apples Testflight service for letting users test the app and thus there is no way around the 99$/year they demand.

> On iOS, you can't share your published link
>   When you publish, any Android user can open your app inside Expo client immediately.
>   Due to restrictions imposed by Apple, the best way to share your published app is to build a native binary with Expo's build service. You can use Apple TestFlight to share the app with your testers, and you can submit it to the iTunes Store to share more widely.

[Source](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/publishing/#on-ios-you-cant-share-your-published)

Comment: You are correct, but I did find a pretty shotty loophole of making a test login to be the author of the app and allowing the client to login to expo on their iphone with those credentials. Apparently, you can only load an app in expo for iOS is you are logged in as the author. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

On iOS after publishing  you must login with same publish credentials to expo client  and run the app from main menu. No way to open the app through direct link without login to Expo Client.

for more details: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/publishing/

Comment: Also, there is no way to choose custom release channels in the expo go menu right now, and I believe `unlisted` apps are functioning as `hidden` apps due to a change in Expo Publishing + App Privacy. e.g. We set our app to unlisted, but users still needed to be part of our expo organization to load it in Expo Go